# Using IN keyword in queries to LDAP (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, ldap

I'm trying to query LDAP from Excel using VBA. It works OK when I'm fetching records by CN using OR keyword, but with IN keyword it fails:

Fails (error 80040e14):

```
Function GetUsersProperty(ByVal users As String, ByVal returnField As String)

    Dim usersProperty As New Collection

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

    cmd.CommandText = _
        "SELECT cn, " & returnField & _
        " FROM 'LDAP://" & GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE").get("defaultNamingContext") & _
        "' WHERE objectClass = 'User' AND objectCategory = 'Person' AND cn IN (" & users & ")"
        'assuming there are multiple users names in colons inside 'users' separated with comma

    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    'On Error Resume Next
    While rs.EOF <> True And rs.BOF <> True
        usersProperty.Add Item:=rs.Fields(returnField).Value, Key:=rs.Fields("cn").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    Set GetUsersProperty = usersProperty

    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Works if I replace `WHERE` under `cmd.CommandText` with

```
        "' WHERE objectClass = 'User' AND objectCategory = 'Person' AND (cn = " & user1 & " OR cn = " & user2 & ")"
```

Problem is that I what to use IN due to easier understanding and easier list formation. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I do not think the problem is VBA related. Since your code compiles and executes then there's nothing wrong with the code. If it doesn't work as expected that's a different issue but you are not facing that either. I recommend you read about the [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) as part of an SQL query.

Comment: Thank you, mehow.
The usage of IN operator is correct as far as I can see. The problem that `cmd.Execute` command does not accept it and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question - the actions I would like to do is not possible due to LDAP architecture limitations.

There is a very good article, describing what one should NOT expect when querying LDAP: http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/74-LDAP-is-not-relational.html